# ActionScript3 banner pause on mouse hover

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to create simple moving banner in ActionScript3/Adobe Flash. Banner consists of multiple images.

My code inside 1. slide and 1.frame

```
img1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, thumb1RollOver, false, 0, true);
img1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, thumb1RollOut, false, 0, true);

img2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, thumb2RollOver, false, 0, true);
img2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, thumb2RollOut, false, 0, true);

img3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, thumb3RollOver, false, 0, true);
img3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, thumb3RollOut, false, 0, true);

img5.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, thumb5RollOver, false, 0, true);
img5.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, thumb5RollOut, false, 0, true);



function thumb1RollOver(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    this.stop();
}

function thumb1RollOut(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    this.play();
}

function thumb2RollOver(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    this.stop();
}

function thumb2RollOut(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    this.play();
}

function thumb3RollOver(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    this.stop();
}

function thumb3RollOut(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    this.play();
}

function thumb5RollOver(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    this.stop();
}

function thumb5RollOut(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    this.play();
}
```

This code works just fine, but only for the first image. On mouse hover movie stops and on release it continues. But for further slides it don't work.

Does I need to seperate each slides code? But again. When I did it it didn't play the movie at all.

On output screen I saw this message:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at banner_flash_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`img2`, `img3` and `img5` are non-existant on your first frame, that's the cause of your type error.

The structure of your movieclip is like this:

```
MovieClip
    frame1
        img1
    frame2
        img2
```

and so on.

If you put all this code on frame 1, it will not work. It can only see `img1`, and it's not able to find `img2`, `img3` and `img5`. Hence the TypeError. Note that if you install a debug player, you'll be able to see linenumbers, which will aid you in tracking down any future problems. You might have to build a debug build to see linenumbers with a debug player, though.

Consider adding a class to the banner via the library. I found a tutorial on that here: http://www.kirupa.com/developer/flashcs3/movieclips_classes_AS3_pg1.htm and otherwise you can probably find it by googling.

So yes.

> Does I need to seperate each slides code?

**Yes, you do.** Or you need to give it a class and dynamically attach the images.